# how to stop print time and timer function using a button

Tags: timer, countdown

I'm working on a countdown timer that allows the user to select a future trip departure date & time, hit a start button to start the countdown, then hit a reset button to invalidate the timer and allow the user to select a different departure date and time, then start again.

everything works pretty well, except for the reset button. the timer invalidates briefly, but then continues the countdown, and the days, minutes, hours, seconds labels continue to update.

I thought that invalidating the timer would freeze values, or I could set all days, minutes, hours, seconds labels to "", and then start button would begin a new countdown. no such luck. right after selecting a new departure date/time, countdown begins, even if start button isn't pressed.

I'm looking for a way to stop the printTime and runTimer functions. thanks for the help.

here's the code:

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var resetBtnStatus: Bool = false

    var timer = Timer()

    let userCalendar = Calendar.current
    let requestedComponent: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.day,.hour,.minute,.second]
    var departureDateTime: Date?

    @IBOutlet weak var departureDateTimePicker: UIDatePicker!


    @IBAction func departureDateTimePicker(_ sender: Any) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss"
        departureDateTimePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handler), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var daysLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var hoursLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var minutesLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondsLabel: UILabel!

    func handler(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss"
        let departureDateTimeString = dateFormatter.string(from: departureDateTimePicker.date)
        departureDateTime = dateFormatter.date(from: departureDateTimeString)
    }


    @IBAction func resetBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if resetBtn.isSelected == true {
                resetBtnStatus = true
            }
            departureDateTimePicker.isHidden = false
            startBtn.isHidden = false
            //        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            //        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss"
            //        let startTime = Date()
            //        let endTime = startTime
            //        let timeDifference =  userCalendar.dateComponents(requestedComponent, from: startTime, to: endTime)
            //        daysLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.day!) Days"
            //        hoursLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.hour!) Hours"
            //        minutesLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.minute!) Minutes"
            //        secondsLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.second!) Seconds"

        }

//    @IBAction func resetBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
//        if resetBtn.isSelected == true {
//            resetBtnStatus = true
//        }
//        departureDateTimePicker.isHidden = false
//        startBtn.isHidden = false
//        //        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
//        //        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss"
//        //        let startTime = Date()
//        //        let endTime = startTime
//        //        let timeDifference = userCalendar.dateComponents(requestedComponent, from: startTime, to: endTime)
//        //        daysLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.day!) Days"
//        //        hoursLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.hour!) Hours"
//        //        minutesLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.minute!) Minutes"
//        //        secondsLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.second!) Seconds"
//    }


    func printTime() {
        if resetBtnStatus == false {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss"
            let startTime = Date()
            let endTime = departureDateTime
            let timeDifference = userCalendar.dateComponents(requestedComponent, from: startTime, to: endTime!)
            let startTimeDouble: Double = startTime.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
            var endTimeDouble: Double?
            endTimeDouble = (endTime?.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)


            daysLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.day!) Days"
            hoursLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.hour!) Hours"
            minutesLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.minute!) Minutes"
            secondsLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.second!) Seconds"

            if endTimeDouble! > startTimeDouble {
                daysLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.day!) Days"
                hoursLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.hour!) Hours"
                minutesLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.minute!) Minutes"
                secondsLabel.text = "\(timeDifference.second!) Seconds"
            }
            else {
                timer.invalidate()
                daysLabel.text = ""
                hoursLabel.text = ""
                minutesLabel.text = ""
                secondsLabel.text = ""
            }
        } else {
            timer.invalidate()
            daysLabel.text = ""
            hoursLabel.text = ""
            minutesLabel.text = ""
            secondsLabel.text = ""
        }

    }

    func runTimer() {
        if resetBtnStatus == false {
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self,    selector: #selector(printTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timer.fire()
        }

        if resetBtnStatus == true {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }



    @IBOutlet weak var startBtn: UIButton!

    @IBAction func startBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        handler(sender: departureDateTimePicker)
        printTime()
        runTimer()
        departureDateTimePicker.isHidden = true
        startBtn.isHidden = true
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var resetBtn: UIButton!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    }
```

Comment: this isn't a true answer, but I developed a workaround by hiding the days, hours, minutes, seconds labels when resetBtnPressed. added .isHidden = false to the labels for when startBtnPressed. Hides and shows how I want, even if timer doesn't invalidate.